# Add avatar field to user component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

```
Joomla 3.9.28

PHP 7.4.21
```

I added a field to the "Users" component to let the users have an avatar photo.

This field is set to "Media" type.

However, in the Administration of the user, when I try to select an image from the server, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred.

0 Invalid controller: name='mediafield', format=''
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Thanks for transferring your question here.  While you wait for feedback/support, please take our [tour].